# add a connection to database not working, asp.net to mdf

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

i am adding a connection in asp.net using visual web developer to sql server database file, it's an MDF file.

when i click test connection i get this:
[alt text http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5186/morric.jpg](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5186/morric.jpg)

can someone please help me set up this connection

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like either the MDF or LDF file(s) are marked as read only.

Comment: right click on the MDF/LDF files and click properties, then un-select the checkbox marked "Read Only"