# not connecting because read-only (sql server, mdf file)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mdf

this is a different question concerning:

[add a connection to database not working, asp.net to mdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360433/add-a-connection-to-database-not-working-asp-net-to-mdf)

i am unable to connect because of the noted error message

the database must be read only? but when i click the properties of the file read only is not checked

is there another way it could be read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely - you can set a filegroup inside a MDF file to be read-only - only that shouldn't prevent you from connecting to it - just from altering anything inside it.

Comment: can you attach the .MDF to a full (non-Express) edition of SQL Server? You could then use SQL Server Mgmt Studio to undo the "read-only" flag on your filegroup(s).

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to mdf as attached file like
  Driver=SQL Server; Server=.\SQLEXPRES; AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=myDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes; make sure to set on this file full windows permissions to Users
via property tab